# Adding field to class of my module ,not working

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

i have a model located in classes folder of my module:

```
public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'myTable',
    'primary' => 'id',
    'multilang' => false,
    'fields' => array(
        'day' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'required' => true),
        'hours' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'required' => false),
        'active' => array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'required' => false),
    ),
);
```

I want to add a field category_id , i done this:

```
public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'MyTable',
    'primary' => 'id',
    'multilang' => false,
    'fields' => array(
        'day' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'required' => true),
        'hours' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'required' => false),
        'active' => array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'required' => false),
        'category_id' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'required' => true)
    ),
);
```

But when i create `new MyTable` , i don't see the new field , i think it's a cache problem but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: do you use any framework ?

Comment: Look at tags , prestashop is there :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved , for those who have the same error , classes inside my module are moved to `/classes` folder ,so you need to edit those classes too.

Answer (score 0):

IT is not a good practice to place any of your class directly in the calsses folder, because those files can be deleted in an auto upgrade.

For best practices, place your classes in override/classes folder. And after that go to cache folder and find file "class_index.php" and delete this file.

Note: class_index.php is an auto generated files by PS in which it indexes all classes and controllers so it saves the time to search a file or class in folders during loading a class or controller. So for any new calss or controller, this file should be deleted else that class or controller will not work. So if you delete it, then on next run or request to PS it will be regenerated automatically and your class will be also indexed in it.

Comment: Thank you,i read all what you said in prestashop doc , but the problem is that this module is not developed by me , i just want to edit it to my need ,this module is not MVC based , and will cause a lot of problems in future upgrades , i will try to correct those stuffs , thanks